# How can we convert date stored as varchar to date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

Here my date values are stored in varchar and i want to get results while searching in between dates
Here is my code please have a look

```
public function get_report($from1,$to1)
{
    $from=DATE($from1);
    $to=DATE($to1);
    $this->db->order_by('customer_account_id','desc');
    $this->db->where('Date(`date`) >= ',$from);
    $this->db->where('Date(`date`) <= ',$to);
    return $this->db->get('customer_accounts');


}
```

my date_format is like this `31-01-2017` and when i use my code like this the result is not obtaining

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `date` function expects `dates` in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. If you change the date values that are stored in `varchar` column to be in that format then you should get the desired results. It will be better still if you convert the `varchar` column to be `date` as this will be faster when you select data from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql CONVERT function to convert value from varchar to date while fetching.